# Inconsistency between XmlReader.Read() and XmlReader.ReadStartElement()

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Trying to understand an "inconsistency" between `XmlReader.Read()` and `XmlReader.ReadStartElement()`. In `reader1` below, everything is expected, namely, it needs 3 reading to read the whole xml; more importantly when reading for the 1st time i.e. reading `<firstname>`, `reader1.Value` is empty. And 2nd reading `reader1.Value` is the text node value.

But in `reader2`, I am expecting the same reading order because as far as I know `ReadStartElement()` internally calls `Read()` and it should only read one `XmlNodeType` e.g. here the `<firstname>`. It's almost as if we can replace `ReadStartElement("firstname")` with a call to check whether it's a start element with name `firstname` and a call to `Read()`. Why is `reader2.Value` not empty right after `ReadStartElement("firstname")` ?
I asked this initially under a question of @lesscode and his explanation is, according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7e4769a(v=vs.110).aspx), `ReadStartElement()` will advance the `XmlReader` to the next node and `reader.Value` is the value of current node. But if so, isn't this inconsistent between `Read()` and `ReadStartElement()` because using `Read()` you have to retrieve the Value afterwards whereas using `ReadStartElement()` you have to retrieve the `Value` beforehand.

```
 var simpleElement = "<firstname>Jim</firstname>";
 using (var reader1 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(simpleElement)))
 {
    var i = 1;
    while (reader1.Read())
    {
       WriteLine($"i = {i++}; value = {reader1.Value}");
    }           
 }

using (var reader2 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(simpleElement)))
{
 // this internally calls Read() which should have ONLY read the 'firstname' start element node. 
    reader2.ReadStartElement("firstname"); 

// prints Jim; but why??? The text node has NOT been read yet!
    WriteLine(reader2.Value); 

    reader2.Read(); //WHY needs this line given text node has been read already?
    reader2.ReadEndElement(); 

}
```

Comment: Post sample of xml including repeating tags.

Comment: @jdweng there is no sample of xml; <firstname>Jim</firstname> is the whole xml; I am just testing how `XmlReader()` works and find this 'problem'.

Comment: @JonSkeet any idea?

Comment: See my solution on following posting.  I use a combination of xmlreader and xml linq which avoids the issue you are seeing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274568/how-to-read-an-xml-file-by-using-xmlreader-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check at the source code on Github: [XmlReader.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs).

As you can see below, the methods have not the same behavior:

```
// Checks that the current node is an element and advances the reader to the next node.
public virtual void ReadStartElement() {
    if (MoveToContent() != XmlNodeType.Element) {
        throw new XmlException(Res.Xml_InvalidNodeType, this.NodeType.ToString(), this as IXmlLineInfo);
    }
    Read();
}

// Checks whether the current node is a content (non-whitespace text, CDATA, Element, EndElement, EntityReference
// or EndEntity) node. If the node is not a content node, then the method skips ahead to the next content node or 
// end of file. Skips over nodes of type ProcessingInstruction, DocumentType, Comment, Whitespace and SignificantWhitespace.
public virtual  XmlNodeType  MoveToContent() {
    do {
        switch (this.NodeType) {
            case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                MoveToElement();
                goto case XmlNodeType.Element;
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
            case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
            case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
            case XmlNodeType.EndEntity:
                return this.NodeType;
        }
    } while (Read());
    return this.NodeType;
}
```

So the `ReadStartElement` method, calls `MoveToContent` wich can make several `Read` calls in order to find a content node. After this, `ReadStartElement` reads the current starting element.

Comment: wow, that totally makes sense now as it perfectly explains why in the sample xml `ReadStartElement()` calls `Read()` twice; once in the `MoveToContent()` and once after `MoveToContent()`. Many thanks and great advice on seeing the source code on Github!

Comment: Hi, have another question about this. I agree that `reader2.ReadStartElement("firstname")` calls `Read()` twice hence the text node has been read already after the line `reader2.ReadStartElement("firstname")`. But why does it still need another call to `reader2.Read()` before calling `reader2.ReadEndElement()`?  I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Because the only way to go from one node to another is to call one of the Read method. Accessing Value property or Name or read an attribute will keep the reader on the current node. So the first call to call to Read() after reader.Value advance the cursor from the Text Node to the next node. And finally, the ReadEndElement advance the cursor from the EndElement to the next node if it exists.

Comment: OK, so if a node has been read and to forward to next node, `Read()` can be called again? Just had a look at the source code for `ReadEndElement()` which, understandably, checks whether the node is an end element first before reading it, i.e. it's not like `ReadStartElement()` which can read the next node. Overall this makes sense now since xml reading should generally is forward-only. Thanks again for this!